# Get cell name that contains a specific text in google Sheets macro

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a small project for myself in Google Sheets.

1. I need to get a cell name (ex. "A2") by searching for a word in a specified row (ex. search for a specific date in row 3).
2. After getting the cell coordinates, I have to write a text in 2 columns down the cell I found (if I find "A2" has the text I am searching for in it, cell "A4" will be set to a value I want

(all of that after pressing a button with a script assigned, it's important, the function is already linked to the button)

I'm trying to do something like this:

Before clicking the blue button
[image: Before clicking the blue button]

After clicking the blue button
[image: After clicking the blue button]

Button script (now)
[image: Button script]

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) that the community can use to see what you'd like to do? Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. You may include your desired output in it as well.

Comment: @Saddles added the images, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

You may use this sample script as a reference for what you would like to do:

> I have also added some explanations of what the code does

```
function myFunction() {
  // Gets your current active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Gets the value of the "F3" cell
  var currentDayCell = ss.getRange("F3").getValue();
  // Row 8
  var row = 8;
  // Column C
  var column = 3;
  // The number of rows to return
  var numRows = 1;
  // The number of columns to return
  var numCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  // Gets the values of the data range
  var values = ss.getRange(row, column, numRows, numCol).getValues();
  // Iterates over the "values" and checks if the current value is equal to the cell of "F3". Also logs "" two cells down on the value where it's the same in "F3"
  values.map(x => x.map((y, i) => y.toString() == currentDayCell.toString() ? ss.getRange(row + 2, column + i).setValue("") : x));
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Comment: thank you very much! you helped me a lot :D

Comment: I have a small issue. If I have to water and the current day is the first of the week, nothing appears

Comment: I'm glad that the initial issue's been resolved, and I'm sorry to hear about the issue that you've encountered. I'm here to help out! However, your comment is already considered a new issue and would be different from your initial question so I'd ask that you post it as a new one, including the detailed information of what you're trying to do and what's currently going on. This is because if your initial question is changed in the comments, other users of the community may be confused. By posting it as a new question, other people, including me can think of what's going on.